# Парсинг сложного XML

Tags: php, xml, xmlparser, simplexml

Есть xml:

```
<planeta-kino>
<movies>...</movies>
<showtimes>
<day date="2017-03-04">
<show full-date="2017-03-04 17:20:00" />
<show full-date="2017-03-04 21:45:00" />
<show full-date="2017-03-04 10:30:00" />
...
<day date="2017-03-05">
<show full-date="2017-03-05 17:20:00" />
<show full-date="2017-03-05 21:45:00" />
<show full-date="2017-03-05 10:30:00" />
...
итд
```

Использую 2 цикла, что бы пробежаться по всем < day > и по всем вложенным < show >

```
foreach ($data->showtimes->day as $day){
foreach ($data->showtimes->day->show as $show){
        echo $show['full-date']."<br>";
}
}
```

Но результат я всегда получаю только по первому блоку < day>< show>

2017-03-04 17:20:00  
2017-03-04 21:45:00  
2017-03-04 10:30:00  
2017-03-04 17:20:00  
2017-03-04 21:45:00  
2017-03-04 10:30:00  
...
итд

т.е. всегда за 2017-03-04 число и ни как не могу добраться до 2го блока < show>. Что в моём цикле не так, подскажите?

Comment: Я в похожем вопросе давал ответ, попробуй это [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/815688/283285)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте

```
foreach ($data->showtimes->day as $day){
  foreach ($day->show as $show){
    echo $show['full-date']."<br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало

Answer (score 2):

Во внутреннем `foreach` нужно использовать полученную переменную из внешнего `foreach`, иначе это не имеет смысла.

```
foreach ($data->showtimes->day as $day){
                                    |
             ------------------------
             ↓
  foreach ($day->show as $show){
    echo $show['full-date']."<br>";
  }

}
```

Comment: так и есть, теперьработает как надо, спасибо

Comment: @AlexSokolov Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию.
Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers