# Как распарсить атрибуты из xml?

Tags: php, xml

Имеется xml файл. 
Фрагмент из него:

```
<offer id="104304" available="true">
<productId>72187</productId>
<price>855</price>
<picture>image</picture>
<vendorCode>10679</vendorCode>
<name>Коробки МДФ для складной двери  Дуб седан</name>
<params>
<param name="Цвет">Дуб седан</param>
<param name="Остекление">Для двупольной двери</param>
<param name="Тип">Для двупольной двери</param>
<param name="Размер">70*24*2037</param>
</params>
</offer>
```

Пытаюсь построить ассоциативный массив для params в виде Цвет=>Дуб седан
Упростив, делаю так:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$item = $xml->offers->offer;
foreach($item as $ii) {
    foreach($ii->params as $iii){
        $attr = $iii->attributes();
        $name = (String)$attr["name"];
        echo $name;
    }
}
```

Но так не получается вывести на экран.

Comment: Возможно это поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814951/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-xml-c-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-php/814958#814958

Answer (score 0):

Простая невнимательность:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$item = $xml->offers->offer;

foreach($item as $ii){  
    foreach($ii->params as $iii){
        $attr = $iii->param->attributes();
        $name = (String)$attr["name"];
        echo $name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($item as $ii){  
    foreach($ii->params as $iii){
        foreach($iii->attributes() as $name => $val) {
           echo $name;
           echo $val;
        }
    }
}
```